# How can I get a list of absolute image URLs from a Django QuerySet?

Tags: django

In Django, what is the best way to construct the absolute path to an image URL when you're using a CDN to serve media files?  In my case, I have a QuerySet of Movie objects, and I want to retrieve the absolute URL of the image attribute of the movie, where image is an ImageField.  Is there any way to do this by using a template tag or the values() function of the QuerySet API?

Answer (score 7):

I solve this by prefixing the url for the model field with the MEDIA_URL value from settings.py. You could create a property on the model that returns this concatenated path as whatever name you'd like.

Example:

```
@property
def get_absolute_image_url(self):
    return '%s%s' % (MEDIA_URL, self.image.url)
```

Comment: The `image.url` will already have the media prefix on it, I believe.

Comment: At the time this question was answered in 2012, the image url did not have the media prefix prepended.