# Django: Get ImageField url in view

Tags: django, view, absolute-path, imagefield

I am trying to get ImageField absolute path in Django view so I can open the image, write on it something and then serve it to user.

I have problem getting absolute path for the image which is saved in media folder.

```
item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
absolute_url = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + str(item.image.path)
```

I get error, that item.image does not have path (`The 'banner' attribute has no file associated with it.`). item.image is ImageField and I'd like to know how to get absolute path of the image saved in image field (within Django view).

Answer (score 47):

When configured correctly, use `.url`: `item.image.url`. Check the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url).

Comment: I tried using .url but it doesn't work.. it works in templates but not in view :/

Comment: Maybe it's caused by the fact that I hve extended ImageField into BannerField... but all i've done there is overwritten clean method.

Comment: @user2225675 How do you manage image files? Seems `item.image` is missing its relative file. Perhaps it was caused by mis-configuration of uploading or you are trying different items in template and view?

Comment: It's the same item in template and the view.. in template it shows w/o  problem.

What do you mean by mnge image files?

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this way?

```
@property
def get_absolute_image_url(self):
    return "{0}{1}".format(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.image.url)
```

see [How can I get a list of absolute image URLs from a Django QuerySet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388172/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-absolute-image-urls-from-a-django-queryset)

Comment: Meanwhile you can find an related example in the Django documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FilePathField.path

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out what was the problem... absolute image path is saved in file variable.

Example (in view):

```
item = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
print item.file # prints out full path of image (saved in media folder)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the image field is called photo:

**Image URL**

```
# Image URL
instance.photo.url

# Image Path
instance.photo.path
```

Find out more in the Django "Managing Files" documentation.

Django 4.1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/files/

**Add Image to Template**

```
 <img src="{{instance.photo.url}}" alt="photo">
```