# Django Is it possible to display images from media subfolders?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the project in which admin(editor) is uploading images to database and they will display in articles and articles minatures (form of a list).

I managed to configure displaying images from the media folder but it is not working in the way i would it like to be.

I would like to upload images in the specific subfolders of "Media" folder. e.g:
blog/media/reviews_images
blog/media/reviews_minatures_images

I know that upload to the specific folders is possible but that is not the point of this question.
I am courious how can i configure MEDIA ROOT to display images from different subfolders of it.

Now I can specify one of this folders as MEDIA ROOT and the images from this folder are displaying correctly but from the other arent displaying at all.

Is it possible to configure that?

my code:

models.py

```
fs_reviews_images = FileSystemStorage(location="blog/media/reviews_images")
class ReviewsImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(storage=fs_reviews_images)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
fs_reviews_minature_images = FileSystemStorage(location="blog/media/reviews_miniatures_images")


class ReviewsMiniaturesImages(models.Model):
    miniature_image = models.ImageField(storage=fs_reviews_minature_images)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    game_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.game_title} {self.description}"
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("reviews", views.ReviewsListView.as_view(), name="reviews"),
    path("reviews/article/<pk>", views.ReviewsDetailView.as_view(), name="reviews-detail")
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "blog/media/reviews_miniatures_images")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

template

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ review.review_minature_image.miniature_image }}" class="card-img-top"
         alt="{{ review.review_minature_image.description }}">
```

I tried a couple of solutions. I tried to pass the diffrent folders in document root argument after commas, a few static functions. None of these works as I expected. I cant find solution in the documents.

I expect to displaying images from different subfolders of "Media" folder under one MEDIA_URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Get ImageField url in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764587/django-get-imagefield-url-in-view)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.url`:

```
<img src="{{ review.review_minature_image.miniature_image.url }}">
```

As an example, this is the level of the path being given for the following attributes:

- `car.photo` gives `<ImageFieldFile: cars/chevy.jpg>`
- `car.photo.name` gives `'cars/chevy.jpg'`
- `car.photo.path` gives `'media/cars/chevy.jpg'`
- `car.photo.url` gives `'http://www.example.com/cars/chevy.jpg'`